# Use pointer to change an array when passing it into a method

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

Suppose I am writing a sorting-array method. At the time I did not know pointer, I usually defined array as global so that it automatically change.
Now I try to use it but it fails, basically it ends up with

```
int a[5];
sort(&a);     // Calling sort
...
// My method
void sort(int *a[]) {
    int key = *a[1]; // I've got a bug right here
    ...
}
```

I am still unfamiliar with using pointers. Moreover I can not use reference, either. Please suggest me some ways to do that.
Thank you so much.

Comment: Please add a tag for the language (probably C or C++)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the square bracket notation *with an index* deferences the pointer (put simply, gives you the variable rather than the address), so you shouldn't have an asterisk there. The following are equivalent (but only for 0!):

```
*a
a[0]
```

If you are in fact trying to use the value of the second element (index 1) in *key*, then you should use:

```
int key = a[1];
```

Additionally, since *a* is an address, *&a* is not useful to you and you should be calling the sort function with only *a*.

Comment: At first, I thought when I call  Sort(&a) then  my parameter *a[] would be the address, so basically I was just trying to interact on address to change array simultaneously.
Am I right with that way of thinking?

Comment: *a[] does match up with passing &a but this creates complications. The problem occurs when you try to access the second element as *a[1]. The square brackets are evaluated first and index into an array of pointers (which you haven't created and didn't want). The * then deferences this to get the first element in that bogus array. This is probably outside the memory space of your actual array and causes the bug. It might work if you do (*a)[1], but don't do this. It's needlessly complex and hard to read, write, and debug. Use sort(a), void sort(int a[]), and int key = a[1].

Comment: Thank you so much!!!
With your, the others' comments and searching on Google, I found that array works the same way with pointer so basically, just passing array is pointer already. 
I don't know it before so I keep declaring global variable. Same thing to JAVA

Answer (score 4):

Change your function to just this :: `void sort(int *a)` or this :: `void sort(int a[])`

And when you call `sort` from the main, you need not call `sort(&a)`, `a` is an array pointer itself, calling `sort(a)` will do it!

Comment: So then in sort(a), is it right that whenever I wanto change in array, I just need to do like *a[0] = 5; ?
I somehow get the idea after reading your explanation

Comment: You need not use *a[0], `a` is a pointer, no point dereferencing it twice! Any changes you make to `a[0]`, `a[1]` will be reflected, but if u do `a = new int[10]` inside your sort function, that wont be reflected in your `main`

Answer (score 3):

Both your passing and using of array are not correct. An array name gets converted into a pointer to its first element. So passing the name is sufficient to modify it, not a pointer to array (You can pass a pointer to array too -- but has to used accordingly in the function and is usually not needed to modify elements of an array).

Call it:

```
sort(a);
```

and use it:

```
void sort(int a[]) {
    int key = a[1]; 
    ...
}
```

In `sort()`, you can use it with the usual array notation.

One thing to note is that you can't get the size of the array in `sort()` using `sizeof` operator as all the size information is lost in `sort()` and all you have is a pointer. So you have to pass the array size as an additional argument.

Comment: Thank for reminding me about sizeof(...) 
I just wonder whether the array will change after implementing sort().
Or you mean I need to have an array of pointer with addresses of values in array?

Comment: I don't get your question. Can you point to the sentence in the answer that you are referring to?

Comment: Cause in your answer, I don't see anything dealing with pointers, so I thought you suggest me to declare pointers inside sort(...)
Sorry for unclarified question. Hope you can explain for me

Comment: In function definition, you only have a pointer. `void sort(int a[]) {}` and `void sort(int *a) {}` are exactly the same. Even though, there's an array notation [], it's just a pointer.

Comment: I did try what you showed me and then it works. However, I am more confused because I can not explain why it does. 
Why do some people using like doSomething(int *a[]) to change array while we can do like you?
And if void sort(int a[]) {} and void sort(int *a) {} like you said, in a function, how can I know which is needed to pass a pointer inside, suppose I have sort( int a, int b, int c). Or it just happens when only one parameter